# Use a trigger like assertion

Tags: mysql, triggers

I know that in MySQL we can't use assertion. I Have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `soggiorno` (  
`idSoggiorno` varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
`price` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 PRIMARY KEY (`idSoggiorno`))  

 CREATE TABLE `prenotazione` (  
`idPrenotazione` varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
`soggiorno` varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
`paymentType` varchar(45) NOT NULL,    
 PRIMARY KEY (`idPrenotazione`))    
 CONSTRAINT `guest_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`soggiorno`) REFERENCES `soggiorno` (`idSoggiorno`)
```

I have to ensure that, if 'price' > 1500, you can't pay with "cash". How can I do that without assertion? I'm thinking for a trigger...Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_prenotazione_before_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON prenotazione
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.soggiorno = IF((SELECT price 
                          FROM soggiorno 
                         WHERE idSoggiorno = NEW.soggiorno) > 1500 
                       AND NEW.paymentType = 'Cash', NULL, NEW.soggiorno);
```

What is does it checks for your desired conditions (if price > 1500 and paymentType is 'Cash') and if it's a match it violates `NOT NULL` constraint effectively preventing a row from being inserted.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/121a6)** demo. *Try to uncomment the last insert statement in the demo and you'll see that it won't let you insert it.*